# Issue with overriding /magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

Tags: magento2

I need to override template `magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml` and I have following setup of files.

Module name : Iwdat_AddressExt278

**Iwdat/AddressExt278/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Info.php**

```
<?php

namespace Iwdat\AddressExt278\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View;

class Info extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_template = 'Iwdat_AddressExt278::order/view/info.phtml';
        parent::_construct();
    }
}
```

**Iwdat/AddressExt278/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo" type="Iwdat\AddressExt278\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info" type="Iwdat\AddressExt278\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info"/>
</config>
```

And I have updated version of template at **Iwdat/AddressExt278/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml** , but it is not overriding the core template.

[image]

Can someone please let me know how to make this attempted template overriding effective, or other possible alternatives?

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Answer (score 0):

To override the template file `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml`, you'll need to follow these steps:

**1. Create the layout file:**

In the `view/adminhtml/layout` directory of your module, create a file named `sales_order_view.xml` and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Iwdat_AddressExt278::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**2. Copy the template file:**

- Create the following directory structure in your module: `view/adminhtml/templates/order/view`.
- Copy the original `info.phtml` file from `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view` to your module's template directory (`view/adminhtml/templates/order/view`).
- Modify the overrided `info.phtml` file as per your requirements.

After completing these steps, your custom template file at `app/code/Iwdat/AddressExt278/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml` will override the original template file. Make sure to clear the cache for the changes to take effect.